# Windows 7: Property Handler works in Explorer but Not FileOpenDialog?

Tags: shell, windows-7, custom-attributes, common-dialog

Working on writing a custom property Handler for our custom file type in windows 7.  I have installed the Windows 7 SDK and built the sample Property Handler.  After registering the handler, it works great in Windows Explorer, but in the common file open dialog the custom values do not appear.  Does anyone know if there is something special I need to do to get the properties to appear in common dialogs?

Explorer:
[image]

File Open Dialog:
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, figured it out.  Here is the deal.  My app is 32 bit and I am on a x64 system.  Because the PropertyHandler is written in x64 to support the shell out of process.  But for the file open dialog it needs to run inprocess, so the x64 dll can not run.  I confirmed this by creating a quick x64 app and the fileopen dialog works the same as the OS.  Hope this helps someone else in my shoes later on, hate answering my own question, but don't want people wasting NRG on this one as I found the solution.

Comment: Hi! Do you know if it is possible to add custom property as column for an existing file type or folder in the file explorer(e.g. in details view)?

Comment: For others mystified about what **NRG** means -> **Energy**! Had to look it up.